# Building dynamic expression with short date

Tags: c#

I have the following code that helps me build dynamic expression. However when I try to compare a Date it converts my value to a full DateTime stamp. How can I get it to build my expression so it will only compare the short date?

```
private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param,
    Filter filter)
{
    MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof (T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        if (filter.Value != null)
        {
            if (property.Name == filter.PropertyName)
            {
                ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(
                    Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value,
                        property.PropertyType));

                if (property.PropertyType == typeof (System.String))
                {
                    constant = Expression.Constant(
                        Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value.ToString().ToLower(),
                            property.PropertyType));
                }
                else if (property.PropertyType == typeof (System.DateTime))
                {


                    constant =
                        Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, property.PropertyType));

                }
            }

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I know it's the Convert.ChangeType that is converting the string to a DateTime, but what I get back is item => item.ClosedOn == 11/11/2014 12:00:00AM, when I want item => item.ClosedOn== 11/11/2014

Comment: Are you missing a closing curly brace? Adding to much space between lines is counterproductive (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Change in last line:

```
filter.Value
```

to

```
datestring
```

Comment: This is of course only a partial answer, but the constant should be date only.